# Mosquitto MQTT: setting the `"ca_certs" to "/etc/ssl/certs/" leads to `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory`

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

Im looking for the corresponding code for

```bash
# this works fine!
mosquitto_sub --capath /etc/ssl/certs/ -u user -P xyz -h hostname.com -p 8883 -t '#'
```

This is my code, which should do the same...

```py
import ssl
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.username_pw_set("user", "xyz ")
client.tls_set("/etc/ssl/certs/", tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) # <- line 16

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("hostname.com", 8883)

client.loop_forever()
```

But it gives me an Exception

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/mqtt.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.tls_set("/etc/ssl/certs/", tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
  File "/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 804, in tls_set
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
```

I do not understand why, as [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) says: *a string path to the Certificate Authority certificate files*

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the actual code it appears to be expecting a path to a single file that holds all the cacerts concatenated together.

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/a4cb435ca2864d073ea3e0e18b0407e4bbe85b16/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L804

```
        if ca_certs is not None:
            context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
        else:
            context.load_default_certs()
```

This just passes the `ca_certs` argument straight to `context.load_verify_locations()` which the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations) implies can take any of 3 named arguments.

> **SSLContext.load_verify_locations(cafile=None, capath=None,
> cadata=None)**
>
> Load a set of “certification authority” (CA) certificates used to validate other peers’ certificates when verify_mode is other than
> CERT_NONE. At least one of cafile or capath must be specified.
>
> This method can also load certification revocation lists (CRLs) in PEM or DER format. In order to make use of CRLs,
> SSLContext.verify_flags must be configured properly.
>
> The *cafile* string, if present, is the path to a file of concatenated CA certificates in PEM format. See the discussion of
> Certificates for more information about how to arrange the
> certificates in this file.
>
> The *capath* string, if present, is the path to a directory containing several CA certificates in PEM format, following an OpenSSL
> specific layout.
>
> The *cadata* object, if present, is either an ASCII string of one or more PEM-encoded certificates or a bytes-like object of DER-encoded
> certificates. Like with capath extra lines around PEM-encoded
> certificates are ignored but at least one certificate must be present.

Since it's not naming the arguments I'm assuming it's being interpreted as the first `cafile` rather than `capath`

Given the path you are passing would normally be considered the default path, I would guess leaving not passing that argument would lead to it calling `context.load_default_certs()` which will load the same set.

Comment: Many thanks four your rich answer! Not passing that argument won't work either, but it is unclear if it is due to the certificate (it just goes into the endless-loop without any callback ever called - while CLI is receiving lots of data with the same config)..

Comment: I think i will make an Issue on GitHub, because IMAHO the docs are really unclear what to put there (not saying clearly file or folder while _file**s**_ hints it's a folder)